# 'math' has not been declared Gazebo 8 Write Plug in Tutorial

Tags: c++, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am following this tutorial --> [click me](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) <--

I am getting this error:

```
**error:** 'math' has not been declared
   this->model->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3(.03, 0, 0));
                             ^
```

Wasn't math imported with some kind of library in the script?

Full script:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace gazebo
{
  class ModelPush : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {
      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;

      // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every
      // simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          boost::bind(&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this, _1));
    }

    // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
      // Apply a small linear velocity to the model.
      this->model->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3(.03, 0, 0));
    }

    // Pointer to the model
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;

    // Pointer to the update event connection
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
  };

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(ModelPush)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16373/%27math%27-has-not-been-declared-gazebo-8-write-plug-in-tutorial/) by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-06-05**:
What's your Gazebo version?

**Comment by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on 2017-06-05**:
It is Gazebo 8.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-06-06**:
You can try adding `#include <gazebo/math/math.hh>` to the top. I believe the tutorial needs to be updated for Gazebo > 7

**Comment by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) on 2017-06-06**:
It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The Gazebo documentation isn't updated, I had to used the ignition library.

```
ignition::math::Vector3<double /* var type */ >(0.03f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

---

Originally posted by [michael1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3329/michael1234/) with karma: 5 on 2017-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0